# Vertical-alignment text in Bootstrap's List Group

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried to vertical align text in Bootstrap's list group (inside of tag `li`) with `display: table-cell; line-height: 50px; vertical-align: middle;`, but it doesn't work at all. Help me with it, please. ;)

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="list-group">


                    <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Byl jsi pořádně prošťouchán uživatelem <strong>hakys</strong>.
                                <form action="my_pokes.php" method="post">
                                    <span class="pull-right">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" name="poke_hakys">Šťouchnout zpět</button>&nbsp;
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_hakys">Smazat šťouchnutí</button>
                                    </span>
                                </form>
                            </li>                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, and then you won't need to override the `list-group-item` style..

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12`">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item text-right">
                    <span class="pull-left">
                    Byl jsi pořádně prošťouchán uživatelem <strong>hakys</strong>.</span>
                    <form action="my_pokes.php" method="post" class="form-inline">
                        <span>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" name="poke_hakys">Šťouchnout zpět</button>&nbsp;
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_hakys">Smazat šťouchnutí</button>
                        </span>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/6H4wBABPGw

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code. The biggest change is that instead of setting up one 12 span column I divided it into three. this makes it easier for laying out items in bootstrap.

Let me know if this helps you.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">Byl jsi pořádně prošťouchán uživatelem <strong>hakys</strong>.</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form action="my_pokes.php" method="post"> <span class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn btn-success" name="poke_hakys">Šťouchnout zpět</button>&nbsp;
    <button class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_hakys">Smazat šťouchnutí</button>
    </span>
    </form>
    </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```